# Colab TPU not computing validation data at the end of each epoch?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tpu

I'm training my model on Colab TPU. But I encountered some confusing behavior of the `model.fit()` API. The problem I got only happened when passing the `validation_data` argument.

#### Scenario 1

```
model.fit(get_train_ds().repeat(), 
          steps_per_epoch = 100,
          epochs = 10,
          callbacks = [lr_callback],
          validation_data = get_val_ds(),
          validation_steps = 100)
```

Returns error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-f929303620ea> in <module>()
     20                     callbacks = [lr_callback],
     21                     validation_data = get_val_ds(),
---> 22                     validation_steps = 100)
     23 
     24 with open("trainHistoryDict", 'wb') as file_pi:

22 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py in _clone_functional_model(model, input_tensors, layer_fn)
    178     input_tensors = nest.flatten(input_tensors)
    179     for i, input_tensor in enumerate(input_tensors):
--> 180       original_input_layer = model._input_layers[i]
    181 
    182       # Cache input layer. Create a new layer if the tensor is originally not

IndexError: list index out of range
```

#### Scenario 2

When using `checkpoint` callback and set the `monitor` as `val_loss`, for example:

```
checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('model_{epoch:03d}-{val_loss:.8f}.h5', 
                                 save_weights_only=True, monitor='val_loss',
                                 save_freq="epoch")
```

Returns error

```
KeyError: 'Failed to format this callback filepath: "model_{epoch:03d}-{loss:.8f}.h5". Reason: \'val_acc\'
```

Besides, when training on GPU, it always shows validation loss every epoch. But, when training on TPU, the validation loss never shows.

Based on the 3 observations, I suspect that validation data is not being assessed on Colab TPU? Is that correct? Is there any way to compute validation data at the end of each epoch?

====
Update:

My data pipeline code is as below:

```
batch_size = 16
gcs_path = "gs://my-bucket/"

train_pattern = gcs_path + "train/*.tfrecords"
train_fns = tf.io.gfile.glob(train_pattern)

val_pattern = gcs_path + "val/*.tfrecords"
val_fns = tf.io.gfile.glob(val_pattern)


def get_train_ds():

    train_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(train_fns, num_parallel_reads=AUTO)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size = len(train_fns), reshuffle_each_iteration = True)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.map(parse_func)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder = True).prefetch(batch_size)
    
    return train_dataset

def get_val_ds():
    val_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(val_fns, num_parallel_reads=AUTO)
    val_dataset = val_dataset.map(parse_func)
    val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder = True).prefetch(AUTO)

    return val_dataset
```

=== Update

```
with tpu_strategy.scope(): # creating the model in the TPUStrategy scope means we will train the model on the TPU

    model = create_model()
    periodic_save = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('model_{epoch:03d}.h5', 
                                 save_weights_only=True, save_freq="epoch")


    hist = model.fit(get_train_ds().repeat(), 
                steps_per_epoch = 100,
                epochs = 5,
                verbose = 1,
                callbacks = [lr_callback],
                validation_data = get_val_ds(),
                validation_steps = 10)
```

Error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-d088df3513e2> in <module>()
     20                     callbacks = [lr_callback],
     21                     validation_data = get_val_ds(),
---> 22                     validation_steps = 100)
     23 
     24 with open("trainHistoryDict", 'wb') as file_pi:

22 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v1.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    807         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    808         workers=workers,
--> 809         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    810 
    811   def evaluate(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    668             steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    669             validation_steps=validation_steps,
--> 670             validation_freq=validation_freq)
    671 
    672     return training_arrays.fit_loop(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py in experimental_tpu_fit_loop(model, dataset, epochs, verbose, callbacks, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, val_dataset, validation_steps, validation_freq)
    271           steps=validation_steps,
    272           verbose=verbose,
--> 273           callbacks=callbacks)
    274       if not isinstance(val_outs, list):
    275         val_outs = [val_outs]

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py in experimental_tpu_test_loop(model, dataset, verbose, steps, callbacks)
    340   test_input_data = iterator.get_next()
    341   per_replica_outputs = current_strategy.run(
--> 342       _test_step_fn, args=(test_input_data,))
    343   output_tensors = {}
    344   for label, output in zip(out_labels, per_replica_outputs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/tpu_strategy.py in run(self, fn, args, kwargs, options)
    344     fn = autograph.tf_convert(fn, autograph_ctx.control_status_ctx())
    345     options = options or distribute_lib.RunOptions()
--> 346     return self.extended.tpu_run(fn, args, kwargs, options)
    347 
    348   @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/tpu_strategy.py in tpu_run(self, fn, args, kwargs, options)
   1093   def tpu_run(self, fn, args, kwargs, options=None):
   1094     func = self._tpu_function_creator(fn, options)
-> 1095     return func(args, kwargs)
   1096 
   1097   def _tpu_function_creator(self, fn, options):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/tpu_strategy.py in tpu_function(args, kwargs)
   1160             device_assignment=self._device_assignment,
   1161             maximum_shapes=maximum_shapes,
-> 1162             padding_spec=padding_spec)
   1163 
   1164       # Remove all no ops that may have been added during 'tpu.replicate()'

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/tpu/tpu.py in replicate(computation, inputs, infeed_queue, device_assignment, name, maximum_shapes, padding_spec)
    913       name,
    914       maximum_shapes=maximum_shapes,
--> 915       padding_spec=padding_spec)[1]
    916 
    917 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/tpu/tpu.py in split_compile_and_replicate(***failed resolving arguments***)
   1378       vscope.set_custom_getter(custom_getter)
   1379 
-> 1380       outputs = computation(*computation_inputs)
   1381 
   1382       vscope.set_use_resource(saved_use_resource)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/tpu_strategy.py in replicated_fn(replica_id, replica_args, replica_kwargs)
   1122         """Wraps user function to provide replica ID and `Tensor` inputs."""
   1123         with _TPUReplicaContext(strategy, replica_id_in_sync_group=replica_id):
-> 1124           result[0] = fn(*replica_args, **replica_kwargs)
   1125         return result[0]
   1126 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    253       try:
    254         with conversion_ctx:
--> 255           return converted_call(f, args, kwargs, options=options)
    256       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    257         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
    530 
    531   if not options.user_requested and conversion.is_whitelisted(f):
--> 532     return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options)
    533 
    534   # internal_convert_user_code is for example turned off when issuing a dynamic

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, update_cache)
    337 
    338   if kwargs is not None:
--> 339     return f(*args, **kwargs)
    340   return f(*args)
    341 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py in _test_step_fn(inputs)
    331 
    332     (distribution_strategy_context.get_replica_context().merge_call(
--> 333         _build_model, args=(model, mode, inputs, targets)))
    334 
    335     (_, outputs, updates, _) = _per_replica_execution_function(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in merge_call(self, merge_fn, args, kwargs)
   2713     merge_fn = autograph.tf_convert(
   2714         merge_fn, autograph_ctx.control_status_ctx(), convert_by_default=False)
-> 2715     return self._merge_call(merge_fn, args, kwargs)
   2716 
   2717   def _merge_call(self, merge_fn, args, kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in _merge_call(self, merge_fn, args, kwargs)
   2720         distribution_strategy_context._CrossReplicaThreadMode(self._strategy))  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2721     try:
-> 2722       return merge_fn(self._strategy, *args, **kwargs)
   2723     finally:
   2724       _pop_per_thread_mode()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    273   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    274     with ag_ctx.ControlStatusCtx(status=ag_ctx.Status.UNSPECIFIED):
--> 275       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    276 
    277   if inspect.isfunction(func) or inspect.ismethod(func):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py in _build_model(strategy, model, mode, inputs, targets)
     55   else:
     56     dist_utils._build_distributed_network(model, strategy, mode, inputs,
---> 57                                           targets)
     58 
     59 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/distribute/distributed_training_utils.py in _build_distributed_network(model, strategy, mode, inputs, targets)
    780     distributed_model = strategy.extended.call_for_each_replica(
    781         _build_network_on_replica,
--> 782         args=(model, mode, inputs, targets))
    783     set_distributed_model(model, mode, distributed_model)
    784 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   2583       kwargs = {}
   2584     with self._container_strategy().scope():
-> 2585       return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
   2586 
   2587   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/tpu_strategy.py in _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
    741     # we're in a tpu.rewrite(), and update TPUMirroredVariable accordingly.
    742     with _TPUReplicaContext(self._container_strategy()):
--> 743       return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    744 
    745   @contextlib.contextmanager

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/distribute/distributed_training_utils.py in _build_network_on_replica(model, mode, inputs, targets)
    740   else:
    741     updated_model = models._clone_functional_model(
--> 742         model, input_tensors=inputs, layer_fn=models.share_weights)
    743     # Callable losses added directly to a functional Model need to be added
    744     # here.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py in _clone_functional_model(model, input_tensors, layer_fn)
    178     input_tensors = nest.flatten(input_tensors)
    179     for i, input_tensor in enumerate(input_tensors):
--> 180       original_input_layer = model._input_layers[i]
    181 
    182       # Cache input layer. Create a new layer if the tensor is originally not

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What's the batch size for the validation set? and the number of samples in val set?

Comment: The batch size is 16, as it for the training set. I'm not sure about the exact number of samples, but I would say around 15000 samples. Besides, I set `drop_remainders` when batching

Comment: are you using tf data from_generator?

Comment: @SoheilStar Just added my data pipeline code in the edit. I load data from GCS bucket

Comment: thanks. I am a little suspicious it is coming from validation. can you remove the validation part and see if the fit function will work?

Comment: Yes. I've tried that - 1) Remove validation in `fit()` function --> works well.  2)Putting val dataset in the place of train dataset, as `model.fit(get_val_ds().repeat(), steps_per_epoch = 100, epochs = 10)` --> works well

Comment: reduce the validation_steps to 10 and run fit with the validation set.

Comment: @SoheilStar I've put the new updates in the edit. Unfortunately, got the same error